# Different File after uploading via FTP

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, file-transfer, checksum

As the title say, when I upload a file (in my case an encrypted jar) via FTP on my server (running Ubuntu 20.04) and try to download it, some bytes of the jar seems to be changed (so also the relative sha checksum).

Does anyone know why this happens and how to "fix"?

Original file details:

[image: original file details]

Downloaded file details:

[image: downloaded file details]

Original file bytes:

[image: original file bytes]

Downloaded file bytes:

[image: downloaded file bytes]

**Update**: apparently this happens only if i upload a file with jar extension. I tried to rename the file from "Test_original.jar" to "Test_original" (without extension) and upload, the sha256 its the same of my file on desktop.

**Update pt.2**:
Apparently on the server the copy matches to the original one, so im assuming something went wrong during downloading / server processing the file when a download request is coming (?)

Comment: Are the results repeatable?

Comment: Yeah, looks like they are

Comment: Or it may be your local computer (antivirus?) modifies the downloaded file. I think jar files may be considered potentially harmful, maybe this is the reason *something* gets triggered.

Comment: I dont really think so since ive only Windows Defender which never flag jar files.. Also its kinda weird that the file size grow up. (In that case should decrease i think)

Comment: Does the same thing happen with *any* jar file or just this one?  You don't mention anything about it being *corrupted*, so I'm assuming that the archive is still valid after download?  Also, what software are you using on Windows for the upload/download?

Comment: Yes, the same thing happen with any jar file. It fixes if i upload the jar file without the .jar extension. The archive isnt valid after the download (cant run it anymore). I tried both MobaXterm and FileZilla

Comment: And on the Ubuntu side, vsftp?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you used a Windows machine in the process and forgot to use the FTP `binary` option.

Since Windows uses different line endings (`\r\n`) than the rest of the world, the default is to translate every `\n` that is not prefixed by a `\r` into a `\r\n`. This makes limited sense with text files, but is destructive to binary files.

How to avoid that depends on the FTP client you use: For the command line client just type `binary` after login, for a GUI client search for the corresponding config setting.

Comment: This was my first guess but then I saw the bytes that differ. IMO they cannot be explained by your hypothesis.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the "text" transfer mode on windows does all sort of funny "translations" - this includes language-dependent substituiions. I have had the same problem with uneducated users uploading MP4 files, and there as well seemingly random substitutions were done. Using `binary` fixed it for good.

Comment: Well, I think you should state this in the answer. Up to this point I believed it's always about `\n` vs `\r\n` only (and *by the what I know about pure FTP* I still suspect it *should* be like this).

Comment: I tried to set my ftp mode to binary via command, but for some reasons, after connecting via 'ftp <host> <port>' and executing the command 'binary' it returns "Not connected."

Comment: I was originally thinking it was a binary-mode problem, but then that wouldn't explain why the same file transfers correctly *without* the jar extension, would it?

Comment: Without the .jar extension the file bytes (after downloading) are the same. Also the problem isnt related to binary or non-binary mode since the mode was already set to binary.